# Silex with PHP built in web server

Tags: php, symfony, webserver, development-environment, silex

I'm trying to run a very simple Silex project in my machine in a development environment before deploying to the hosting server.

According to Silex official webpage guide ([LINK](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html#php-5-4)) this is a simple way to test locally:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t web web/index.php
```

My simple handler is:

```
$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
    return 'Hola Mundo!';
});
```

My problem is that I'm receiving a 500 server error, but I'm not very familiar with this environment, so I'm looking for suggestions on how to:

1. View Logs & debug this type of errors
2. Make sure php caching is not messing with my development process

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Just in case it helps, I'm using PHP 5.5.18. But I'm almost certain this shouldn't be the problem, since when pushed in the production server the same source works just fine. I just want to work locally to avoid the constant hassle of pushing and recompiling in the server.

```
 PHP 5.5.18 Development Server started at Wed Apr  8 18:47:12 2015
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem! The server start command that worked for me was:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t web
```

(getting rid of the last param)

Maybe because of difference from PHP 5.4 ~> 5.5.18, still got the problem of the error logs... In mac osx, no error logs appear in /var/log/apache2/

Comment: When using PHP's built-in web server you'll never see errors logged on apache's logs, instead you should try to enable debug mode in index.php add ```$app['debug'] = true``` and also add the [monolog service provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/monolog.html) to log errors and information about handling the request.

Comment: Great thanks! You're right, now that I look into it, I understand why/how they are printing into console in an example using: `'monolog.logfile' => 'php://stderr'` (in the params when registering the monolog service)